# Catch custom exception C++

Tags: c++, exception

I have an exception class:

```
#ifndef OBJECTEXCEPTION_H_
#define OBJECTEXCEPTION_H_

class ObjectException: public std::logic_error
{
public:
    ObjectException (const std::string& raison)
            :std::logic_error(raison){};
};

class Object1Exception: public ObjectException
{
public:
    Object1Exception (const std::string& raison)
    : ObjectException(raison){};
};

#endif
```

I have a method which throw this exception:

```
void Object1::myMethod(int type) {
if (type == 0) {
    throw new Object1Exception(type);
}

...
}
```

Now I use this method:

```
try{
    obj1->myMethod(0);
}
catch(Object1Exception& error){

}
```

But I have this error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tp::Object1Exception*'
```

I don't understand why the exception is not caught.

Comment: Never say `new` in C++ unless you're an expert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code `throw Object1Exception(type);` without the `new`; you are throwing a *pointer* to an exception, not an exception itself.

<sup>BTW, as commented by [polkadotcadaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2428400/polkadotcadaver), the error message was pretty clear, it told you about throwing an instance of some pointer type `throwing an instance of 'tp::Object1Exception*'`....</sup>

Comment: I just want to point out also that the error message told you exactly this - "tp::Object1Exception*", the * meaning pointer.